# LVM extend filesystem based on increasing existing disk size

Tags: linux, rhel, filesystems, lvm, vmware

before couple months we extend root XFS filesystem partition size ( it was only 20G ) by adding the VMDK sdi disk and increase the root filesystem by +100G

```
[root@DB_OP_SERVER ~]# pvcreate /dev/sdi
  Physical volume "/dev/sdi" successfully created.


[root@DB_OP_SERVER ~]# vgextend VG_DB /dev/sdi
  Volume group "VG_DB" successfully extended


[root@DB_OP_SERVER ~]# lvresize --size +100g /dev/mapper/VG_DB-lv_root
  Size of logical volume VG_DB/lv_var changed from .... 
  Logical volume VG_DB/lv_var successfully resized.


[root@DB_OP_SERVER ~]#  xfs_growfs /root
meta-data=/dev/mapper/VG_DB-lv_var isize=512    agcount=7, agsize=6553600 blks
         =                       sectsz=512   attr=2, projid32bit=1
         =                       crc=1        finobt=0 spinodes=0
data     =                       bsize=4096   blocks=42729472, imaxpct=25
         =                       sunit=0      swidth=0 blks
naming   =version 2              bsize=4096   ascii-ci=0 ftype=1
log      =internal               bsize=4096   blocks=12800, version=2
         =                       sectsz=512   sunit=0 blks, lazy-count=1
realtime =none                   extsz=4096   blocks=0, rtextents=0
data blocks changed from 42729472 to 45350912

df -h /
Filesystem                Size  Used   Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VG_DB-lv_root 120G   110G   10G  93% /
```

now we want to increase the root filesystem by additional +50G in order to achieve root filesystem size to 170G

so we update the VMDK disk ( by edit setting in vSphere client to **150G** )

what the steps that needed to increase the root filesystem again ?

Comment: You should be able to do that with `pvresize /dev/sdi` and normally using `lvresize` command (you shoudln't need the `vgextend` as the disk is already in the VG.

Comment: IMHO the filesystem grow command should be: ` xfs_growfs /`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did the following steps , and by this we get the right partition size

first we need to rescan the disk

```
echo 1 > /sys/block/sdi/device/rescan

pvresize /dev/sdi

lvresize --size +50g /dev/mapper/VG_DB-lv_root

xfs_growfs /root
```

Comment: I didn't mentioned the rescan as for this type of activity I'm restarting the machine to get fresh information.

Comment: actually no need restart because the rescan is works